# Передать серверу инициализирующий пакет PDU для RDP

Tags: c++, c, rdp

Как в C++ передать серверу инициализирующий пакет PDU для RDP ?
по вот этой документации https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240842.aspx

Comment: А Вы пробовали что-то сделать самостоятельно? У нас тут помогают тем, кто уже что-то пытался сделать. Мы не делаем чужую работу.

Comment: я не понимаю как вообще взаимодействовать с этим протоколом. куда вообще смотреть чтобы по этой документации https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240842.aspx работать с сервером.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383464(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: И ещё 2 open source проекта: [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com) и [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org)

Comment: @ixSci, а это можно было бы оформить ответом.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не уверено, что это то, что нужно. Я просто нагуглил пару ссылок. Сам я с RDP ранее не работал

Comment: @ixSci, ни один человек не рождается с «умением гуглить», а уж про то, что реализации можно посмотреть не только в примерах из ms/dn, но и в «живых» свободных проектах, некоторые программисты не знают и в зрелом возрасте (лично встречал таких людей в «дикой природе»). так что, думаю, ваши комментарии (с небольшим дополнением-оформлением) вполне достойны стать одним из ответов.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что это лучший путь, но я бы начал с изучения [Remote Desktop Services API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383464(VS.85).aspx) , затем посмотрел бы на одни из наиболее популярных открытых решений. Их код должен дать достаточно понимания, как работать с RDP. Как я понял, одни из наиболее известных проектов это [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com) и [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org). Их код доступен по ссылкам выше.